# Handle notifications to pause app and how to test on iPad

Tags: ios, event-handling, notifications

I would like to "pause" my app when the iPad receives notifications, like push notifications from other apps, local notifications like alarms and so on, that is showing a small pop up window. I have tried to look for what event to listen to but can not find it.

I have implemented this in my view controller for applicationWillResignActive and hope there is something similar for this kind of notifications.

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                         selector:@selector(pauseMyApp:) 
                                             name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification 
                                           object:nil];
```

I'm sure that I have read about it somewhere but can not recall. Would appreciate if someone can redirect me to the right documentation or just give a short piece of code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must seem stupid to have asked this question, as the answer is the same as I already is using :-) Just implement the applicationWillResignActive. Documentation can be found here for those (like me!) who has a problem finding it again...

[UIApplicationDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillResignActive%3a)